# ASP.NET MVC 3 Data Annotation for Mobile and Phone Numbers (Edited)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I write the validation using data annotation in writing telephone number such as "094-4567" or mobile number such as "09129705678" etc.?

```
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PhoneBook.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Telephone Number Required")
        [?]
        public string Telephone Number {get; set;}
    }
}
```

I really don't know what to do...

Comment: Are you only accepting US Phone Numbers? Do you allow extensions like 123-456-7890 x1234? What about somebody in the US using a mexican cell phone and they enter the number you would dial to reach it from the US such as 52-1-625-1140504?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use regular expression attribute like so:

```
namespace PhoneBook.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Telephone Number Required")
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
        public string Telephone Number {get; set;}
    }
}
```

It will match numbers like: *0123456789, 012-345-6789, (012)-345-6789* etc.

You can learn more about this expression here: [How to use Regular expression for validating Phone Numbers](http://www.authorcode.com/how-to-use-regular-expression-for-validating-phone-numbers-in-net/)

Comment: Use @"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4}).*$" instead to allow extensions to be tacked onto the end.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Provided phone number not valid")]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try for simple regular expression for Mobile No

  [Required (ErrorMessage="Required")]
  [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Wrong mobile")]
   public string Mobile { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
namespace PhoneBook.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Telephone Number Required")
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
        public string Telephone Number {get; set;}
    }
}
```